# mongoDB versions 5.x on arm64 architecture - minimum ARMv8.2-A required

Tags: mongodb, raspberry-pi, arm, arm64, raspberry-pi4

It looks like starting with version `5.0.0`, mongoDB requires at minimum `ARMv8.2-A` or later microarchitecture to run.

That unfortunately disqualifies single board computers like:

- Raspberry Pi 4 (BCM2711 / ARM Cortex-A72 / ARMv8.0-A)
- Odroid C2 (Amlogic S905 / ARM Cortex-A53 / ARMv8.0-A)
- Odroid N2+ (Amlogic S922X / ARM Cortex-A73 + Cortex-A53 / ARMv8.0-A)
  and others.

Indeed latest Docker mongoDB 5.0.0 image won't run on rPi4.

Would anyone know if this is final decision and users of these low cost home server computers will be stuck with 4.4.x, or is it something that might change?

Is there a more detailed reasoning behind this change?

Answer (score 1):

This is unlikely to change. See [this ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-54407) for the similar bump on x86-64. You can try looking in the source tree for the arch that is required and using `git blame` to find the relevant server ticket which may provide additional context.

You should be able to build your own (community) MongoDB binaries by passing `CCFLAGS=-march=<something>` and referencing https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.1.0/gcc/x86-Options.html#x86-Options for the option values. This naturally isn't going to be a MongoDB-supported build.

Comment: Thank you for comprehensive answer. It's bit of a shame it's made to run only on the latest HW, despite running well up to v4.4 in the home use scenarios on the single board devices, that are just few years old. Sigh.
Slowly accepting the reality of things becoming obsolete too soon.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-compilation is possible for modern MongoDB releases, but it requires quite a few steps. I have unofficial step-by-step instructions and binaries [here](https://github.com/themattman/mongodb-raspberrypi-binaries).